# Do I need to have a "references" column in both my Question and Answer models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

If I have a `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationship between Questions and Answers:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Do I also need to modify the migration files to use "references":

```
class CreateAnswers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :answers do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.references :question

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :answers
  end
end

class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :questions do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.references :answer

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :questions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign key only goes in the model that `belongs_to` the other.